# learning jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

what is the meaning of this code:

```
aoData.push({"name":"more_data","value":"my_value"});
```

where is `more_data` and `my_value` get from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*more_data* and *my_value* are strings...
that means that value never change! They aren't variables!

aoData is an array, and push is adding in the array that values...

push function is like **$arrayvar[] = "test";** on the PHP

It adds the value to the end of the array...

Answer (score 0):

`aoData` is an array defined somewhere and with `push` more elements are pushed into the array.

See:

[Push Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)